# Ordered list of points along polylines/curves on an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I have images with some combination of polylines/polycurves. My aim is to recover an ordered list of points along these polylines/polycurves.

Using opencv connectedComponents I can isolate each of these polylines/curves in the image, and then I tried to get an ordered sequence of points with these steps:

```
    num_labels, labels_im = cv2.connectedComponents(input_image)     
    ske = skimage.morphology.skeletonize(labels_im==1)
    x,y =np.where(ske)
    cnt = np.vstack([x,y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)        
    recovered_points = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 100, False)
```

However, the points in recovered_points don't follow along the original polyline, they are points on the original polyline but in raster order, from let to right, bottom to top, and that's not what I want. Below you can see the input_image(original image), the skeleton image, and the recovered_points points (notice they came out rotated).
[image]

I have also tried to use findContours on the connected components of the input_image and then approxPolyDP on the contours, but these are contours around the original polylines, so the recovered_points go along the polyline on one side and the comeback on the other and close on the first point, which is neither what I want. See image of the extracted contour below.

[image]

Is there anyway in opencv or scikit-image or other library to recover the ordered points along the original polylines/curves?

Comment: You can follow the yellow line by starting at the top yellow pixel and checking its neighbors to find the next pixel that is yellow. Continue until you reach the lowest yellow pixel.

Comment: I'd like to avoid an iterative approach in python (like tracing the polyline) so that it's faster processing. But if I don't find an alternative with existing image processing primitives I guess I'll have to do something like what you suggest.

Comment: Could we get the original image too?

Comment: @martinako I hope that this will be useful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61515945) to your case also.

Comment: Ok, I see, it's finding the centroid of the connected component and then scanning the points around that centroid to get a different than raster ordering. However, that wouldn't work well for non-convex shapes. @rayryeng the original image is a section of an occupancy grid for robot navigation while moving along a corridor, so in the original there is only another connected component corresponding to the other side of the visible wall, the rest is blank.

Comment: That really doesn't help me at all. I asked for the original to help craft a solution. I'll leave this alone then. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library called [skan](https://jni.github.io/skan/) for skeleton image analysis in Python which will do what you want, although it might be too heavyweight for you. But it solves the same problem you're having, which is that you need to loop over pixel neighbours, which is slow in Python. (It uses [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org) for speed.) The [skan.Skeleton](https://jni.github.io/skan/api/skan.csr.html#skan.csr.Skeleton) class will do what you want, specifically, `skeleton.path(0)` will give you the pixel indices of the 0th path, and `skeleton.coordinates[skeleton.path(0)]` will give you their coordinates.

Specifically with your code:

```py
import cv2
import skimage.morphology
from skan import Skeleton

# [... missing code...]
num_labels, labels_im = cv2.connectedComponents(input_image)     
skeleton_image = skimage.morphology.skeletonize(labels_im==1)
skeleton = Skeleton(skeleton_image)
path_coordinates = skeleton.coordinates[skeleton.path(0)]
```