# OpenCV Detecting points along curved lines

Tags: python, opencv, line, curve, robotics

I am new to openCV programming and I would like to do something which seems fairly simple in my mind but I haven't found any useful solutions.

I am building a robot that needs to follow lines on an image drawn by a user. Let's use [image: line drawing] as a reference.

Obviously, the line will need to be converted into points in order to navigate to. I have attempted using Houghlines but that seems to only work for straight lines. Using contours seems promising to me but the result I get from findContours is a set of points on either side of the line such as: [image: drawing with contours]I am not surprised as this is the definition of a contour.

My question is, is there a way to detect points along the line and not on either side of it?

Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, I had this same question a couple of years ago and I've not come across a solution since. There are some aspects that make this a difficult question in general. E.g., if you have a closed loop, where should the start point be; if you have a Y-fork, should your function return a path for each possibility; if you have a noisy/broken path, how do you reconstruct it, especially problematic if there are neighbouring paths.

Comment: That said, this answer in a related question could be useful to you: [Ordered list of points along polylines/curves on an image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62507676/8944057).

Comment: Hi, @eugenhu thanks! This seems to have helped a lot.